# I think I broke the SBS-2008 tag

Tags: support, retag-request

OK, so after discussions in chat about the future of [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008), I created a tag synonym *the wrong way*, from [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008) `<--` [windows-sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2008) . Realising I made the wrong one, I went to the mod tools and hit "swap". Everything reflected correctly in the Tag Synonyms console, so I merged the two tags together.

Now, everything seems broken. [windows-sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-sbs-2008) redirects to [sbs-2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sbs-2008), which is empty and doesn't exist, and is showing 0 questions (correctly).

Official SE team: Halp please!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's SBS, isn't it broken by definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not broke. It doesn't redirect in my browser, nor in the alternate I just tested (which has never been to that tag's page before). I think your browser has the redirect cached and isn't actually checking with SF's servers.

Comment: No dice, just tried it in IE (which should on its own indicate that it has a completely empty cache and browser history) and I'm still seeing the bad redirect

Comment: Also just tried on the iPhone and iPad, both of which have never been to that particular tag before

Comment: I just tried it on two different servers with Lynx, no redirect... I'll try my phone.

Comment: Just tried from my Android, still no redirect. Network proxy?

Comment: Yes... it could be a caching proxy on our network...

Comment: Nope, it's not our network cache

Comment: Unofficial update: Something somewhere was cached. General consensus in chat was it could have been something cached at Stack Exchange, as it was unreliably reproduced by different people. After nearly 2 hours everything has corrected itself.

Comment: I've had similar issues at home and the problem turned out to be the cache on my firewall/proxy, which is so easy to overlook.